# How to assign Action to a Button in perl cgi?

Tags: perl, email, button, textbox, cgi

So I have a button in my CGI Perl. On clicking that button I need to assign a action in perl CGI, on clicking that button a New text-area should open with specified width in the same page with a submit button. Please help me on how I can proceed. Here is the code which is not really working for me. On clicking on submit button, I what to email the message to a email id

Here I print the button

```
print button('email',"email me","reqts()");
```

Here is the `opentextarea` subroutine

```
sub reqts {

   print "<p><em>Enter your Message here</em><br>";
   print textarea(-name=>'Comments',
                      -rows=>10,
                      -columns=>50);
   print submit('Action','Send');

}
```

On clicking this button the subroutine is not getting called.

This button is on a html form in another subroutine

```
sub actions {
print
  start_html(),
  start_form(-action => 'com.pl'),
  submit(-name => 'submit', -value => 'View com.pl'),
   end_form,
  print button('email',"email me","reqts()"),   # this is the button
  start_form(-action => 'about.pl'),
  submit(-name => 'submit', -value => 'About Us');
  end_form,
  end_html;
}
```

Comment: Putting raw HTML into your Perl code is a terrible idea. Using the HTML generation functions from CGI.pm is a pretty bad idea too. You should look at a templating system (e.g. Template Toolkit).

Comment: Can you point me to any links which talks about it ?

Comment: http://www.template-toolkit.org/, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004767.do (I have some small financial interest in that one), https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Toolkit

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` attribute (the third argument to `button`) should be a JavaScript function, not Perl function. You should study how CGI and webpages work.